# Show full chatbot discussion?

Tags: chatbots, virtual-reality

I am designing a guiding chatbot that shows you around in a virtual tour and helps you make a decision about buying that property. Now as it is a moving bot which also shows and points out on the screen, it shows its message from its chat head (screenshot below) and you can answer by typing or clicking a suggested response at the bottom.

In my design, you can't scroll up and see previous messages. How important is it in this scenario to be able to see the complete chat history? If keeping chat history is important, where should I place it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What's the idea behind having the chatbot head's floating around? Are you using it to draw attention to specific details? I think it's a cool idea, but I think that you need a good reason to display questions and answers in a separate space, with all the drawbacks you're discovering.

A few more questions:

- What kind of information are people gathering during these virtual tours?
- Anything they'd want to keep a reference of?
- What kind of decisions are they making at this point?
- What are the next steps in the user journey after this virtual tour?

I think more context would help us share some advice. Thanks!

Comment: It is basic tour bot. For example you want to buy a property and want to short list some before visiting, this chat bot will show the property around and answer your basic questions like, how much it will cost and what options are available in scheme. How far is it form important places like school, work, hospital etc. This is basically like conversation so it is not that crucial to keep the history and see it. But user sometimes want to see over all flow to go back and see any details if they forgot, like how far was it from school and how much exactly it cost.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the conversation history would be entirely based on context (i.e. pertains to exactly what the user is looking at when that message was received). It seems likely that the history would just be a lot of:

> "*Do you like this one?*"
>
> "No, I'd like to see another"
>
> "*How about this one?*"
>
> "No, I'd like to see another"...

As such, it seems that you'd have a few options:

1. Stick with the chatbot interaction and somehow **inject the context into the "Chat History" UI** you come up with (e.g. `11:15 am — Viewed property 123 Address Ln`)
2. **Provide a "Viewed Properties" section** near the user's profile management that allows them to skip all of the chatbot hand-holding and just see what's important.
3. **Completely ditch the chatbot concept.** Unless there's more to it that you haven't included in the post, I don't think this is an appropriate use case for a chatbot. It seems that the important features would only be to somehow "View Details", "Contact Seller", "Make Offer", and "View Next/Previous Property". I think the chatbot gets in the way and makes each of these functions require more mental processing power. This appears to be an investment service—I would expect an investment service to present a more serious tone. A floating head asking me questions would not convey professionalism (IMO).

Comment: Well i need floating head to show the specific detail and this is not just investment tour bot. It is real estate tour bot which will show you different properties offered by one builder (who buys our service).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is reminding me a little of Clippy. Does the chatbot need to be a floating head on the screen? The chatbot panel at the bottom seems a nice solve, and you can add a slider for the user to review history.